# use React Hooks to change the elements class Name and siblings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this function component in react hooks.
and need when I click in any element in the list to change className to 'active' 
and remove the className from the other elements

```
const SideBar = () =>{
  const [activeClass, setClass] = useState('');

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li> <Link onClick={() => setClass('active')} className={activeClass} to="/"> Home </Link> </li>
        <li> <Link to="/about"> About </Link> </li>
        <li> <Link to="/form"> Form </Link> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you must be using `react-router-dom` so you can use rect-router-dom api to determine the active item

```js
import {
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

const SideBar = () =>{
  const [activeClass, setClass] = useState('');
  let { pathname } = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li> <Link className={pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''} to="/"> Home </Link> </li>
        <li> <Link to="/about" className={pathname === '/about' ? 'active' : ''}> About </Link> </li>
        <li> <Link to="/form" className={pathname === '/form' ? 'active' : ''}> Form </Link> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const SideBar = () => {
      const isActive = path => (match, location) => {
        if (!match) {
          return false;
        }
        return match.url === path;
      };

      return (
        <div className="sidebar">
          <ul>
            <li> <NavLink isActive={isActive('/')} activeClassName="active" to="/"> Home </NavLink> </li>
            <li> <NavLink to="/about" isActive={isActive('/about')} activeClassName="active"> About </NavLink> </li>
            <li> <NavLink to="/form" isActive={isActive('/form')} activeClassName="active" > Form </NavLink> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: I don't know about section 2 but your section 1 solution worked well, thanks :)

Comment: Section 2 is also valid using `react-router-dom` however, I am not 100% sure about the property name of url in match object `match.url`. but 1st solution is simple and easy to understand

Answer (score 3):

So instead of maintaining only active/not active, you need to maintain which `index` in your links is active.

You can do this by this way:

```
const SideBar = () =>{

  //setting the initial index as 0 to activate `/` route by default.
  const [activeLinkIndex, setActiveLinkIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="sidebar">
      <ul>
        <li> <Link onClick={() => setActiveLinkIndex(0)} className={activeLinkIndex === 0 ? 'active' : ''} to="/"> Home </Link> </li>
        <li> <Link onClick={() => setActiveLinkIndex(1)} className={activeLinkIndex === 1 ? 'active' : ''} to="/about"> About </Link> </li>
        <li> <Link onClick={() => setActiveLinkIndex(2)} className={activeLinkIndex === 2 ? 'active' : ''} to="/form"> Form </Link> </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as the correct answer in that case. Happy that it helped you :)

Comment: something wrong here .. when the user refreshe the page and he is in "form" page .. the active class will be in "Home" li bet the user is in the form page

Comment: Yes, this would not persist when the user refreshes the app. Zohaib Ijaz's answer above works fine for that case :)